# How to create a script to scan for .vsd files and convert to .vsdx files and place them in a destination folder.

Tags: powershell, visio

so like the title said, I have over a thousand .vsd files that I need to convert to .vsdx. However they are scattered in sub folders within a directory.

My question: is it possible to create a script to search a directory for all .vsd files, convert them to .vsdx and place them in a certain folder?

We already have a scrip for converting .vsd files to .vsdx in a single directory, but I'm not sure how to get the rest of the script to do what I need it to do.

Thanks in advance.

```
$directoryToUpdate='C:\Users\username\Desktop\vsd\'
$visio= New-Object -com Visio.Application
foreach($vsdFile in (get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate\*.vsd")){
   write-host "Working on $vsdfile"
   $doc=$visio.Documents.Open($vsdFile.FullName)
   $vsdxFileName=[io.path]::ChangeExtension($vsdFile,'.vsdx')
   $doc.SaveAs($VSDXFileName)
   $doc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line `get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate\*.vsd"`

to

`get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate" -recurse -filter *.vsd`

This will search for .vsd files even under subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for that! We made the change an ran it. It scanned all the sub-folders for .vsd files, however the script is not saving them as .vsdx.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have visio to test this out. Thought you said you had that 'file saving part' figured out. Anyway, do u run into errors or the just nothing happens when you run it? Does the files get saved anywhere else other than the intended directory? Have you tried debugging in ISE?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
$directoryToUpdate='C:\Users\username\Desktop\vsd\'
```

to

```
$directoryToUpdate='C:\Users\username\Desktop\vsd\*'
```

and change:
    `"$directoryToUpdate\*.vsd`
to
    `"$directoryToUpdate\*.vsd" -Recurse`

Now it will search recursively and saves it in the working directory, i dont know anything about powershell and figured this out in 5 minutes..

And thanks for sharing your powershell script, i used it myself to convert vsd to vsdx files :)